# Selnium element text value where the By object is actually being sought by text()

Tags: selenium

Consider this code, please:

```
        By byCheckAll = By.XPath("//span[text()='Check all']"); 
        IWebElement thingy = BrowserWindow.Instance.Driver.FindElement(byCheckAll);
```

When I am troubleshooting an issue, I observe that the Text property of the thingy element is an empty string:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLVET.png)

I am looking at why the element is not interactable, and notice this, so I wonder what element is even being found.

I don't see how seeking an element by text, not receiving an error, and having the text be empty can happen. Please explain. THANKS!

EDIT: It is challenging to identify how much code/information is relevant to a question. So I add this in response to the comments.

The method in question is this:

```
        public void CheckAll()
    {
        ClickButtonToDrop();
        By byRootDiv = By.XPath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'ui-multiselect-menu')]");
        var webElements = BrowserWindow.Instance.Driver.FindElements(byRootDiv);
        IWebElement rootElement = null;
        foreach (var webElement in webElements)
        {
            if (webElement.Displayed)
            {
                rootElement = webElement;
                BrowserWindow.Instance.HighlightElement(webElement);

            }

        }


        Element clickAllLink = new Element(rootElement, By.ClassName("ui-multiselect-all"));
        //By byCheckAll = By.XPath("//span[text()='Check All']/parent::div[@tag='a']"); // get the span, then the parent link
        By byCheckAll = By.XPath("//span[text()='Check all']"); // get the span, then the parent link
        IWebElement thingy = rootElement.FindElement(byCheckAll);

        //clickAllLink.Highlight();
        //clickAllLink.Click();

    }
```

rootElement is a div in which the IWebElement thingy lives.

The HTML of the highlighted DIV is

Check all

Uncheck all

Visit Check-In

The same HTML as displayed in the Chrome developer tools with the highlighted div (highlight method in above code)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j7Jm.png)

No error is thrown up to the point where thingy object is set which is where my breakpoint is which I have set a break point to achieve the information in the watch window screen shot.

Comment: Can you specify which page are you scraping?

Comment: Please add or give a link to the entire html

Comment: the screenshot shows that text is empty, so you need to change your xpath, to not use text

Comment: @AdrianJimenez, what she is saying is the selector using that text search finds an element that contains no text. She is wondering how that XPath search returns an element containing no text.

Comment: anyways, you need to provide full code, html and any errors you get while executing your code, thanks